# Why this guilt discrepancy in human beings?

Tags: human-error

I believe no person is born a criminal.

Then why do some people have compunctious guilt after a wrongdoing even when they were raised in an unhealthy family and some people have no guilt at all even when they were raised in a healthy family?

Why this guilt discrepancy in human beings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lack of guilt [is related](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3937069/) to [psychopathy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychopathy), although there could be other reasons for it, e.g. ideological self-justifications, like breaking a law you don't agree with. Psychopathy is [partially inheritable](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2242349/), which means the genetically-unexplained variance is usually attributed to enivronmetal differences.

The propensity for guiltlessness is part of a narrower trait (of psychopathy) called "[callous-unemotional traits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callous_and_unemotional_traits)", and these can be identified around the age of 7, according to one (fairly cited) study of [Viding 
 et al. (2005)](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1469-7610.2004.00393.x). Although the abstract of this paper is a bit... abstract, its intro is a bit more insightful what it is talking about:

> ‘Mark does not feel guilty if he has done something
>   wrong, he does not show feelings or emotions, and he
>   is rarely helpful if someone is hurt.’ This description
>   of one of the 7-year-old children (name changed) in
>   our twin study captures the core emotional impairment
>   of individuals with psychopathy. Psychopathy
>   in both childhood (psychopathic tendencies) and
>   adulthood involves both affective-interpersonal
>   impairment (callous-unemotional traits; e.g., lack of
>   empathy, lack of guilt, shallow emotions) and overt
>   antisocial behaviour.